# Read OSGI bundle version

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, karaf

I'm interested how I can read OSGI bundle jar file version with Java before I deploy it? Is there a way to extract this data before deploying it?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with standard Java:

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("myjar.jar");
Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
Attributes mainAttributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
String bundleVersion = (String) mainAttributes.get(Constants.BUNDLE_VERSION);
```

Constants class comes from *org.osgi.framework* package.

Comment: What other way are you thinking of? There is no standard library that analyzes the JAR file. You can call the functions of Felix or Equinox directly, but I think they are in internal packages so you cannot be sure that the same functions will exist within the new version. You can also start an embedded OSGi container, deploy the jar file there and use the container to analyze the JAR but I think it would be insane :). There is a library called org.apache.felix.utils to parse clause[] expressions (like the value of Import-Package or Bundle-SymbolicName header).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the version it might be completely overkill, but in general a really good way to read all kind of bundle data is to use [bnd](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd). Many tools are built on top of bnd, but it's easy to use as a library as well.